# Typescript error in angular/ramda mapAccum, using an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ramda.js

I'm struggling to get ramda working
in an angular 6 / typescript environment.

```
"ramda": "^0.25.0",
"@types/ramda": "^0.25.24"
```

that's how I've been starting.

```
 const addP = (p1,p2) => ({ x: p1.x+p2.x,y: p1.y+p2.y });
 const accum = (a,b) => [addP(a,b),addP(a,b)];
 console.log(
   JSON.stringify(
     R.mapAccum(
       accum,
       {x:0,y:0},
       [{x:10,y:10},{x:100,y:100},{x:200,y:200}]
     ),
   null,2);
```

which gives:

> error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => { x: any; y: any; }[]'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '(acc: any, value: any) => [any, {}]'.
>   Type '{ x: any; y: any; }[]' is not assignable to type '[any, {}]'.
>   Property '0' is missing in type '{ x: any; y: any; }[]'.

How can this be fixed?
I've tried several generic type declarations, but they've all failed to work.
Why is

> Property '0' is missing in type '{ x: any; y: any; }[]'. ?

I'm new to typescript though.
Is it possible to use an interface along with the type declaration?

```
interface IPoint {
   x: number;                                                                                                
   y: number;                                                                                                
};
```

This seems to require objects generated with "new" at some point, right?
But I want to keep it more basic at first.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your functions cope with each other signature.

```
const addP = (p1,p2) => ({ x: p1.x+p2.x,y: p1.y+p2.y });
const accum = (a,b) => [addP(a,b),addP(a,b)];
```

Signatures are

```
addP(param1, param2): {x: number, y: number }
accum(param1, param2): [{x: number, y: number }, {x: number, y: number }]
```

Your error states this

> Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => { x: any; y: any; }[]'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '(acc: any, value: any) => [any, {}]'.

This means you should return something along the lines of

```
accum(param1, param2): [{x: number, y: number }, {}]
```

So try with

```
const accum = (a,b) => [addP(a,b), {}];
```